# Can I connect to remote oracle database with client side javascript

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am creating a browser extension using java script. I would like to execute a PL/SQL block on a remote oracle database within my network from the extension. I couldn't figure out a way to establish database connections for oracle db from client side. Is anybody aware of any options that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such any option is available...why don't you use a webservice and call the webservice via ajax in javascript and execute the query at the webservice back-end ?